# Get-ADUser -Server: add port

Tags: powershell, active-directory, get-aduser

I need to connect to port 636 of a server and I'm using the "`-Server`" option. The official doc says that you can put "Fully qualified directory server name and port", but it doesn't work for me, i tried to put "`server:port`" and "`server port`" and doesn't work.
Which is the corret syntax?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What happens when you use `server:port`?

Comment: Port 636 is used with LDAP SSL. Powershell's AD cmdlets use ADWS and the port being used is 9389. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/service-overview-and-network-port-requirements). If you must use port 636, you will have to use ADSI

Comment: When I use `server:port` I see this: "_Impossible to contact the server. Maybe the server doesn't exists, is inactive or the Web Active Directory services aren't up in the server._"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) and [FID-FB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12083620/fid-fb). Posting your discussions as answer to help other community members.

> Port 636 is an TCP port for LDAP SSL. To use the port 636, you need to
> enable the ADSI on the sever.
>
> references:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/service-overview-and-network-port-requirements